# MODIS LST maximum value composite

Tags: modis, composite

I am using eight day composite MODIS LST data MOD11A2. How do I make a monthly composite from four 8-day composite data taking the maximum value out of four in the output raster?
Initially I went for Raster Composite tool in ArcGIS 10.2.2 but that caused all void values to be 0K in the output which is not possible. 
As I want values of all pixel for further analysis, how can I get the monthly composite for it?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? A good question on this site requires some effort from you. Please visit the [tour] to learn about our focused Q/A format, then [edit] your post to include more details.

Comment: Check google earth engine questions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/154180)